# Как добавлять строку в БД, имеющий id внешней таблицы

Tags: mysql, yii2

Делаю синхронизацию с системой.
Допустим в упрощенном варианте имею 2 таблицы `events` и `organaizers`

```
events:
id
description
organaizer_id

organaizers:
id 
sid
name
```

organaizer_id таблицы events связано с полем id таблицы organaizers
Делаю синхронизацию. Допустим, мне приходит 10 000 записей, которые я добавляю в таблицу events
С учетом того, что таблицы связаны, то чтобы добавить строку, мне нужно сперва сделать запрос к events, получить id органайзера зная его sid, и только потом произвести INSERT. 
Получается 10 000 лишних запросов. А если таких связанных столбцов 7 - то 70 000 лишних запросов.

Как другое решение, думал сперва сделать запрос на выборку всех органайзеров, прогнать foreach и составить массив соответсвий sid и id. Но если в таблице несколько тысяч записей, а добавить мне надо не 10 000 записей, а одну, то решение тоже становится не лучшим. 
Есть ли какие-то инструменты в yii2, которые смогут сделать это более оптимизировано?

Comment: Загрузите сразу все записи во временную таблицу, а потом одним запросом на основании её и таблицы organaizers добавляйте записи в events.

Comment: Во временную таблицу добавить все записи таблицы organaizers?

Comment: Во временную таблицу добавляются те самые 10к записей, которые "приходят". А кстати, откуда они приходят и в какой форме?

Comment: Через SOAP. Тогда придется 10к запросов на добавление делать во временную. Можете привести пример этого одного запроса?

Comment: `INSERT INTO events(description,organaizer_id) SELECT t.description, o.id FROM organaizers o, temporary_table t WHERE o.sid = t.sid;`